# add a column in python with rows number

Tags: python

I have a dataset like these

| state | sex | birth | player |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QLD | m | 1993 | Dave |
| QLD | m | 1992 | Rob |

Now I would like to create an additional row, which is the id. ID is equal to the row number but + 1

```
df = df.assign(ID=range(len(df)))
```

But unfortunately the first ID is zero, how can I fix that the first ID begins with 1 and so on

I want these output

| state | sex | birth | player | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QLD | m | 1993 | Dave | 1 |
| QLD | m | 1992 | Rob | 2 |

but I got these

| state | sex | birth | player | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QLD | m | 1993 | Dave | 0 |
| QLD | m | 1992 | Rob | 1 |

How can I add an  additional column to python, which starts with one and gives for every row a unique number so for the second row 2, third 3 and so on.

Comment: start the range function from like this range(1, len(df)-1)

Comment: I got an error message, does not match length of index

Comment: try range(1, len(df)-1)

Comment: Got also an error

Comment: `range(len(df))` is the same as `range(0, len(df))`, so you need to increment both boundaries: `range(1, len(df)+1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df['ID'] = pd.Series(range(len(df))) + 1
```